# Struts 1 action tag input replacement in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am trying to migrate the project from struts 1 to struts 2.5.16, so in the previous struts-configuration file there are many input tags that are used like as below:

```
<action name="Form" path="/activities"
 type="-----" validate="true"
 scope="request" input="/applications.jsp">
 <forward name="ActivitiesView" contextRelative="true"
     path="/abc.jsp" />
```

So what will be the replacement for input from above code chunk in structs2?

Comment: Have you considered checking out the Struts 2 documentation? There is no equivalent to the action `input` property in S2.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following documentation.

https://www.infoq.com/articles/converting-struts-2-part1

https://www.infoq.com/articles/migrating-struts-2-part2

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Migration+Guide

Remember, migration from struts 1 to struts 2, requires a lot more than just replacing config file.